# Is there any Online testing Emulator available for Samsung galaxy tab 10.1?

Tags: android, android-emulator, eclipse-plugin

I would like to test application specifically in Samsung galaxy tab 10.1 in 3.1 OS version. So, any online testing option available?

Answer (score 4):

You can look at solutions provided by [DeviceAnyWhere](http://www.keynotedeviceanywhere.com/). They provide you with devices where you can install and test native application. All the other online emulators available let you test only web based applications.

Answer (score 2):

answer to your question is no.... even if they exists that will allow you to test your Mobile Web Apps only not your Android Native apps.

To test Android Native apps in any device you can define ADV.

In Eclipse, click on Run in the toolbar then Run Configurations. Select your application and click on the Target tag. You can then select which AVD to use or set it to manual so it asks you each time you run the app this way you can define any Device Configuration...

See [image] and select device from Eclipse [image]

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks mate I double check your links to see if I am wrong.. cheers

Comment: Thanks Jigar for your response but can you suggest some way how can we test application in such device where we can not buy every device to test :(

Comment: explained in above answer and image too provided

Comment: Dude I know about create emulator and screen resolution and every thing but I am just concerned about same testing like real device tablet due to hardware specification testing. as some sites are providing online emulator so same way does any other way exist?

Answer (score 2):

belove link for all samsung device that are available for online testing .

http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action